# Oracle Performance Issues

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I'm new to Oracle.  I've worked with Microsoft SQL Server for years, though.  I was brought into a project that was already overdue and over budget, and I need to be "the Oracle expert."  I've got a table that has 14 million rows in it.  And I've got a complicated query that updates the table.  But I'm going to start with the simple queries.  When I issue a simple update that modifies a small number of records (100 to maybe 10,000 or so) it takes no more than 2 to 5 minutes to table scan the table and update the affected records.  (Less time if the query can use an index.)  But if I update the entire table with:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyFlag = 1;
```

Then it takes 3 hours!

If the table scan completes in minutes, why should this take hours?  I could certainly use some advise on how to troubleshoot this, since I don't have enough experience with Oracle to know what diagnostics queries to run.  (I'm on Oracle 11g and using Oracle SQL Developer as the client.)

Thanks.

Comment: `UPDATE` involves writing undo and redo data and updating the indexes. It's not just table scan.

Comment: If many rows already have `MyFlag` set to `1`, then `update MyTable set MyFlag = 1 where MyFlag <> 1` will perform better. Also, if you _have_ to update all the rows, you will get better performance by dropping indexes and triggers first, then doing the update, then recreating the triggers and indexes.

Comment: @GriffeyDog - watch out if MyFlag is nullable

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Certainly. Change it to `where MyFlag is null or MyFlag <> 1` if that is the case. I also should have suggested _disabling_ the triggers instead of _dropping_ them.

Comment: I just came back here to mark a post as my answer, but the post was deleted.  I'm not sure what the proper etiquette would be int his case.  Do I mark the remaining answer as my accepted answer?

Comment: @DeadZone, if you've taken the advice of the deleted question, you may want to reconsider. The author has deleted his answer in light of the fact that it is probably not suitable for your problem. That said, you do have the option of *answering your own question* and marking it as correct. It's ok to accept your own answer to your question, generally. It might get voted down though if it is not a recommended solution :)

Answer (score 4):

When you do the `UPDATE` in Oracle, the data you are modifying are sequentially appended to the redo log and then distributed among the data blocks by a process called `CHECKPOINT`.

In addition, the old version of the data are copied into `UNDO` space to support possible transaction rollbacks and access to the old version of data by concurrent processes.

This all may take significantly more time than pure read operations which don't modify data.